# Elasticsearch and kibana, BI data structure

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have an api where a customer comes in, the customer is sent to several 3rd party applications to work out the best possible product for them to use.

I am considering using elasticsearch and kibana as a bi tool for data analysts, they are not hugely experienced so it is going to be down to me to provide a flexible data structure for them to use.

My main question is that I would like to know if I should store data in a flattened structure or to use a more nested option, and whether or not this is an appropriate use case, perhaps there is a better solution or technology to build up a data warehouse.

```
{
    "Source": "ppc",
    "firstName": "john",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "emailAddress": "john@doe.com",
    ... // Other rich meta data
    "logsOf3rdParty": [
        {
            "dateSent": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000",
            "result": "Accepted",
            "commission": 10
        },
        {
            "dateSent": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000",
            "result": "Rejected",
            "commission": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kibana does not yet have support for nested documents, so you would not be able to make use of the visualization tools, but need to write all the queries yourself for the visualizations.

So a flattened structure would be easier to start with.